# API to IBM Rational Requirement Composer

Tags: ibm-rational

We have been using ReqPro to a great extent by taking the advantage of the API DLLs. We basically develop .NET application and used the DLLs to store data to the ReqPro projects with great ease.

Now, we are looking at possible ways to move to RRC. For this, we need to know how we can achieve the same features.

As RRC is web based, it might have some services that can be used for such things.

The basic requirements are inserting requirements, traceabilities, history etc to RRC and retrieving the same.
Back to top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at OSLC - this is a REST-based interface to RRC that will allow you to access and write to RRC.  It may not cover all the capabilities you require - but should be a good start.  http://open-services.net/ - and then look at the RM specification.

Hope that helps

anthony

p.s Another good place to cross-post this question is the forums on jazz.net - there is a specific forum for RRC.

Comment: I read, this is only available for reporting scenarios. So it is a pull only feature. The push scenarios are more important for me.

Comment: My post on Jazz forum (https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19940) is lying idle. I do not think people are active on that forum.

Comment: So how can one download OSLC interfaces for RRC? I could not locate the link on the site listed in your answer. Is it a service that any application can call? I have a .NET application that needs an interface to RRC.

Comment: The OSLC specs is taliking about reporting and integration with other Jazz based products.